# What are symbolic variables in MATLAB? How they are different from normally used variables?

Tags: matlab

What are symbolic variables in MATLAB?Are they data type or class?

Following are Links of mathworks pages for MATLAB classes and MATLAB data types
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-types.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html

But neither of the two above links mentions the term symbolic variable?

Some websources mention that symbolic variables are used in calculus
Normally/generally the variables used in MATLAB have data type scalar or double but why we can't use them in calculus?Why we have to first define variable as symbolic?

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html They are not fundamental matlab classes, so not there.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation ([1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isequal.html)), symbolic variables are a data type:

"Compare the double and symbolic representations of 1. *`isequal` returns 0 (false) because double and symbolic are distinct data types.* To return 1 (true) in this case, use `logical` instead."

```
usingIsEqual = isequal(pi,sym(pi))
usingLogical = logical(pi == sym(pi))
```

```
usingIsEqual =
  logical
   0
usingLogical =
  logical
   1
```

The Symbolic Math Toolbox User's Guide confirms this interpretation every here and there. As already noted in a comment, the symbolic data type is likely not listed in the pages you linked to because it is not provided by MATLAB itself (the core component), but rather by a toolbox.

By the way, symbolic *functions* are treated as a separate data type in the documentation: ([2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html))

```
symfun - Create symbolic functions

Syntax
------
f = symfun(formula,inputs)

[...]

Output Arguments
----------------
f - Function
symbolic function (symfun data type)
    Function, returned as a symbolic function (symfun data type).
```

Regarding the use of symbolic or floating-point variables, this is up to you. If you are taking an introductory calculus course, you will probably be expected to come up with analytical solutions for the problems you are given. In that case, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) can also be a useful tool to check your manual calculations.